# Trying to update SQL database with update command

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
// Find controls for on edit. 
DropDownList ddlLocation = (DropDownList)(sender as ListView).EditItem.FindControl("ddlLocation");
TextBox txtQuestion = (TextBox)(sender as ListView).EditItem.FindControl("txtQuestion");
Label lblLocationID = (Label)(sender as ListView).EditItem.FindControl("lblLocationID");

// Set strSQL to empty string.
String strSQL = "";

// Develop SQL call.
strSQL = "";
strSQL += "UPDATE Question ";
strSQL += "SET LocationID = '" + ddlLocation.SelectedValue + "', Question = '" + txtQuestion.Text + "' ";
strSQL += " WHERE LocationID = " + lblLocationID.Text ;

// Define the network connection to the SQL Server database.
SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2020LJCDT"].ConnectionString);

// Set up the SQL command object
SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;
objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objSqlCommand.CommandText = strSQL;

// Define the input parameters
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", ddlLocation.SelectedValue);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", txtQuestion.Text);

// Open the connection
objSqlConnection.Open();

// Execute sql. Get number of rows affected. 
numberOfRecords = objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Close the data reader and the connection.
objSqlConnection.Close();
```

I have a problem where my update command is not working properly. The problem arises with the updating the `LocationID` for some reason. I can update the `Question` with no problem just not the `LocationID`. I'm selecting the `LocationID` in a drop-down list and it's passing the values correctly but will not update the database. Does anyone see anything wrong?

Here is a screenshot of my database table:

[image]

These are the values being passed:

```
UPDATE Question 
SET LocationID = '2086', Question = 'Test123'  
WHERE LocationID = 2087
```

Comment: Remove the single quotes aound `'2086'` - and use parameters!

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Everything looks OK, but a couple of FYIs from reading it: 1) you don't need single quotes around 2086 since LocationID is an INT (but I think SQL will translate this), 2) you are creating parameters but you're not using them.
Any chance there's a foreign key or constraint on LocationID?

Comment: @jefftrotman The LocationID is a foreign key.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @marc_s I changed all to parameterized queries. There is still problem thou. The SQL is successful but the LocationID is not being updated. The Question attribute is the only one that is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the single quotes aound '2086' and use the parameters in your string:

```
const string strSQL = "UPDATE Question " +
    "SET LocationID = @LocationID, Question = @Question " +
    " WHERE LocationID = @OldLocationID";

// Define the network connection to the SQL Server database.
SqlConnection objSqlConnection = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["2020LJCDT"].ConnectionString);

// Set up the SQL command object
SqlCommand objSqlCommand = new SqlCommand();
objSqlCommand.Connection = objSqlConnection;
objSqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
objSqlCommand.CommandText = strSQL;

// Define the input parameters
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", ddlLocation.SelectedValue);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Question", txtQuestion.Text);
objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldLocationID", lblLocationID.Text);
```

Comment: Are you sre that there is a record with an id that matches the current value in `lblLocationID.Text` then? I doubt it. Are you getting an exeption?

Comment: Yes, there is a record. No exception.

Comment: And you are not getting an exception? Then you are looking in the wrong database.

Comment: It's looking into the right database because when I change the information in the txtQuestion box it updates the database. But the LocationID does not change.

Comment: What is `ddlLocation.SelectedValue` and `lblLocationID.Text` when you put a breakpoint on the line that executes the statement? Did you try to hardcode the values?

Comment: ddlLocation.SelectedValue = 2086   lblLocationID.Text = 2087

Comment: The values are in the comment above. Yes, I created a SQL call in MSSMS with the hardcoded values and it works.

Comment: Did you really copy my code? What if you convert the id to an `int`? `objSqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OldLocationID", Convert.ToInt32(lblLocationID.Text));`

Comment: Yes, I have copied your code. Changing it to an int did not fix the issue. In my database, I know the LocationID is a foreign key int the Question table.

Answer (score 0):

Put a breakpoint on this line:

```
// Execute sql. Get number of rows affected. 
numberOfRecords = objSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When you get to hit, copy the value of objSqlCommand.CommandText and paste it into SSMS and execute it there.  What results do you get?

Comment: All that is doing is getting how many affected rows in the database. For this instance, it is 1.

Comment: So the query is updating the row correctly when you run it that way?

Comment: I have to things I'm trying to update, LocationID and Question. So, when the update is sent to the database the Question attribute is updated but not the LocationID attribute.

Comment: Wait, so if you execute the query at the very end of your question in SSMS, the Question column of the Question table updates but the LocationId of the Question table does not?

Comment: I'm starting to suspect there's something like a constraint or a trigger that is causing the update to fail or be undone.

Comment: How would I find that?

Comment: First thing I would try is, in SSMS, right click on the table in Object Explorer and click on Script Table as->Create To-> New Query Editor window.  Then look through script that is generated for anything mentioning the locationId column

Comment: Here what is came up. I don't see anything causing this.

Comment: And you're sure that there is a LocationId 2086 in the Location table?

Comment: Yes, there is a LocationID = 2086.

Comment: I'm kind of at a loss. Let me think a bit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212642/discussion-between-isiah-jones-and-kevin).